# Best place to insert page variable into drupal view?

Tags: drupal, view

I have a view that displays the top level of a taxonomy vocabulary. When that is being viewed from a page about a different taxonomy vocabulary, I would like to customize the links from the view to include a parameter of the taxonomy category currently being viewed. Does anyone have a recommendation where this can be acccomplished? Would that be in a preprocess function, a views field template, or a hook_page_alter?

Answer (score 0):

Use pathauto module or go to individual term edit page and set the path you want